# You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''14
>
> ') UNION (SELECT * FROM staff WHERE city_id = '368' AND gender = '' at
>   line 1

Code:

```
(SELECT * FROM staff
     WHERE city_id = '2' AND gender = 'MALE' AND staff_status != '3'
     ORDER By s_level ASC LIMIT '$new_sixty')
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM staff
     WHERE city_id = '2' AND gender = 'FEMALE' AND staff_status != '3'
     ORDER By s_level ASC LIMIT '$new_forty');
```

Comment: issue has to be with your variable `'$new_sixty'`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the ' ' from the limit

```
(SELECT * FROM staff WHERE city_id = '2' AND gender = 'MALE' AND staff_status != '3' ORDER By s_level ASC LIMIT $new_sixty) UNION 
    (SELECT * FROM staff WHERE city_id = '2' AND gender = 'FEMALE' AND staff_status != '3' ORDER By s_level ASC LIMIT $new_forty);
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

) UNION (SELECT * FROM staff WHERE city_id = '368' AND gender = 'FEMA' at line 1..